# AJAX call inside auto refresh method not getting called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have one one method inside the auto refresh method. It is making an AJAX call. My requirement is that I have to execute `n` number of requests and simultaneously display the result, so I have one method for executing requests and one for displaying the result.

The method to display the result is inside the auto refresh method. But my problem is my `auto_Refresh` method is getting blocked unless all the requests are completed and the final result is returned. I want to display the results asynchronously. My code was working till last week. I don't know what happened suddenly to prevent it working. Can somebody provide me the solution?

```
// setting the refresh interval and calling execute method. 
setRefreshInterval();
executeDeployment();

//My Execute method
function executeDeployment() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Release/ExecuteCommandDemo",
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{DeploymentId:"' + DeploymentId + '",iswebapicall:"' + iswebapicall + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                try {
                    var result = data;
                    var finalStatus = data[0].FinalStatus;
                } catch (ex) {
                    LogEvent("LogRelease.executeDeployment", ex.message);
                }
            },
            error: function (msg)

        });
    } catch (ex) {
        LogEvent("LogRelease.executeDeployment", ex.message);
    }
}



//my refresh method
function AutoRefresh() {
    getDeploymentStatus(DeploymentId, ProjectId, true);
}

// getDeploymentStatus method
try {
    var timeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Release/getDeploymentStatus",
        type: "Post",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{DeploymentId:"' + DeploymentId + '",ProjectId:"' + ProjectId + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (res) {
            try {....
            }
```

I have set the refresh interval to 1000ms but still my      `GetdeploymentStatus` is not executing unless the completing execution is done. I mean to say auto refresh method is getting blocked somehow and not getting called after the specified interval.

```
          //GetDeploymentStatus Method

     function getDeploymentStatus(DeploymentId, ProjectId,freshRequest)
  {
 try {
    var timeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Release/getDeploymentStatus",
        type: "Post",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{DeploymentId:"' + DeploymentId + '",ProjectId:"' + ProjectId + '",timeZoneOffset:"' + timeZoneOffset + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        async:false,
        success: function (res) {
            try {
                $('#dynamicOutput').html("");
                //if (freshRequest) {
                //    var resultStatus = "Requested";
                //    $('#resStatus').text(resultStatus);
                //}
                if (res != "") {
                    if (res[0].deploymentStatus == "Scheduled") {
                        $('#resStatus').css("color", "black");
                    }
                    if (res[0].deploymentStatus == "Succeeded") {
                        $('#resStatus').css("color", "green");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#resStatus').css("color", "red");
                    }
                    $('#resStatus').text(res[0].deploymentStatus);
                    //$('#lblDeploymentName').text(res[0].deploymentName);
                    //$('#lblEnvName').text(res[0].EnvName);
                    var data = res;
                    $.each(data, function (index) {
                        //debugger;
                        $('#stopdeployment').hide();
                        if (res[0].StepStatus == "Stopped") {
                            $('#resStatus').text("Stopped");
                            testStr = '<div class="panel-heading"><div       class="form-group"><label> Package ID :' + data[index].PackageId + '</label><br /></div><div class="form-group"><label> Step name :' + data[index].StepName + ' Step Details : ' + data[index].StepDetails + '</label><br /></div><div class="panel panel-body"><div class="form-group">' + data[index].StepStartTime + '<br />' + res[index].StepOutput + '<br />' + '<br />' + '<label style="color:orange">' + res[index].StepStatus + '</label>' + '<br />' + data[index].StepEndTime + '</div></div></div>';
                            $('#dynamicOutput').append(testStr);
                            $('#dynamicOutput').show();
                        }
                        if (res[0].StepStatus == "Succeeded") {
                            testStr = '<div class="panel-heading"><div class="form-group"><label> Package ID :' + data[index].PackageId + '</label><br /></div><div class="form-group"><label> Step name :' + data[index].StepName + ' Step Details : ' + data[index].StepDetails + '</label><br /></div><div class="panel panel-body"><div class="form-group">' + data[index].StepStartTime + '<br />' + res[index].StepOutput + '<br />' + '<label style="color:green">' + res[index].StepStatus + '</label>' + '<br />' + data[index].StepEndTime + '</div></div></div>';
                            $('#dynamicOutput').append(testStr);
                            $('#dynamicOutput').show();
                        }
                        else if (res[0].StepStatus == "Failed") {
                            testStr = '<div class="panel-heading"><div class="form-group"><label> Package ID :' + data[index].PackageId + '</label><br /></div><div class="form-group"><label> Step name :' + data[index].StepName + ' Step Details : ' + data[index].StepDetails + '</label><br /></div><div class="panel panel-body"><div class="form-group">' + data[index].StepStartTime + '<br />' + res[index].StepOutput + '<br />' + '<label style="color:red">' + res[index].StepStatus + '</label>' + '<br />' + data[index].StepEndTime + '</div></div></div>';
                            $('#dynamicOutput').append(testStr);
                            $('#dynamicOutput').show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
            catch (ex)
            { LogEvent("LogRelease.getDeploymentStatus", ex.message); }
        },
        error:function(msg)
        { alert("Error while View Log Release. Please contact to   administrator"); }
    });
}
catch (ex)
{ LogEvent("LogRelease.getDeploymentStatus", ex.message); }

      }
```

Comment: It's hard to see the logic flow in the code you posted as some of the functions don't seem related. Also, remove `async: false`. It will block the UI (as you've seen) and is considered incredibly bad practice to use.

Comment: Show us GetdeploymentStatus

Comment: If i don't put async:false then i am not getting results in sequence. Sequence is important here. If i have 3 requests 1,2,3 then result should be displayed as 1,2,3 only. If i remove async:false then i am getting result as 2,3,1 and sometimes 3,1,2 etc. so i have used async:false